# How to wait anime.js animation to complete on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have animation with [animejs](https://animejs.com/) that change `.text` position using `translateY` from 0 to 400px.

The animation is start with the button and `duration` is about 4000ms.

The problem is every time I click on the button the animation is start even though the last animation is not complete.

How each time the animation is start, it should wait to last animation to complet. But the animation (that still execute), need to complete much much fatser duration, so the next animation will start. I'm not sure how to do that if animejs support it.

Because right now, the animation is breaking every time I click the button.

If it possible to solve this without extra global variable it will be nice.

```js
function down() {
  
 anime({
  targets: '.text',
  translateY: [0, '300px'],
  duration: 4000
 });
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  down();  
  
});
```

```css
.wrap-text {
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.text {
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js" integrity="sha256-BuxrUdr/4YoztQLxT6xmdO6hSQw2d6BtBUY1pteGds4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="btn">anime text</button>
<div class="wrap-text">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could try disabling your button on click for the duration of the animation :)

Comment: I known. but I can't. this is just an example for events that can happends not from click but from timer for example.

Comment: Very late, just for everyone else: You can add a function for different events (like complete):  https://animejs.com/documentation/#beginComplete. Then you can set a global variable (I know OP does not want that), for example.